# Sphinx - exclude filter by multiple attributes

Tags: php, indexing, sphinx

I'm querying an index that has records created by users. Since my application can have multiple types of users, the table has CreatedByType and CreatedById.

I want to exclude results that are created by a certain, specific user.

```
// Exclude $userId from the results
$this->Client->SetFilter('CreatedById', $userId, true);
```

However, this will obviously exclude results from all user types with id of `$userId`. Likewise:

```
// Exclude $userId from the results
$this->Client->SetFilter('CreatedByType', $userType, true);
```

will exclude results from all users of type `$userType`.

How can I combine two attributes into a constraint and do an `AND` query on them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can compute a virtual combined attribute, and filter on that.

```
$this->Client->setSelect("*, IF(CreatedById=$userId,1,0)+IF(CreatedByType=$userType,1,0) as myfilter");
$this->Client->setFilterRange('myfilter',0,1);
```

(0 means neither matched, 1 means one matched, 2 means both matched. So the setfilterrange, excludes documents where both match!)